# Change a shape on JavaScript canvas to become an image

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a code here which is for a player which is a shape currently. How do I change this shape to become an image?

```js
let player = {
  x: 300,
  y: 565,
  size: 25,
  vx: 5,
  draw: function () {
    ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.size, this.size);
  }
};
```

I want it to be an `img.png`.

Comment: You're looking for the `.drawImage()` function. Read more on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage).

Comment: Check this out: https://workshops.hackclub.com/platformer and pay attention to the `createSprite` function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [`drawImage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) method with canvas.

Below is an example. The main difference is `ctx.drawImage` however it's a good idea to wait until all images are loaded as well, added an example of that as well.

```js
const playerImage = new Image();
playerImage.src = 'https://i.picsum.photos/id/315/200/200.jpg?hmac=cE5OEQSh9gvXqkP0fkrmaSbqLfc_KQdDPtH7yBbeuiQ';

const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

const player = {
  x: 10,
  y: 20,
  size: 25,
  vx: 5,
  draw: function () {
    ctx.drawImage(playerImage, this.x, this.y, this.size, this.size);
  }
};

// Wait until the image is loaded.
playerImage.addEventListener('load', () => {
    player.draw();
});
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```